# How to transform particular code piece from Spark 1.6.2 to Spark 2.2.0?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to pass my Spark 1.6.2 code to Spark 2.2.0 in Java.

```
 DataFrame eventsRaw = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM my_data");
 Row[] rddRows = eventsRaw.collect();
 for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < rddRows.length; ++rowIdx)
 {
     Map<String, String> myProperties = new HashMap<>();
     myProperties.put("startdate", rddRows[rowIdx].get(1).toString());
     JEDIS.hmset("PK:" + rddRows[rowIdx].get(0).toString(), myProperties); // JEDIS is a Redis client for Java
 }
```

As far as I understand, there is no `DataFrame` in Spark 2.2.0 for Java. Only `Dataset`. However, if I substitute `DataFrame` with `Dataset`, then I get `Object[]` instead of `Row[]` as output of `eventsRaw.collect()`. Then `get(1)` is marked in red and I cannot compile the code.

How can I correctly do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataFrame` (Scala) is `Dataset<Row>`:

```
SparkSession spark;

...

Dataset<Row> eventsRaw = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_data");
```

but instead of `collect` you should rather use `foreach` (use lazy singleton connection) :

```
eventsRaw.foreach(
   (ForeachFunction<Row>) row -> ... // replace ... with appropriate logic
);
```

or `foreachPartition` (initialize connection for each partition):

```
eventsRaw.foreachPartition((ForeachPartitionFunction<Row)) rows -> {
   ... // replace ... with appropriate logic
})
```

Comment: It works with `collect` (compiles). What do you mean by using `foreach`?

Comment: Yes, but `JEDIS` is not serializable.